# pending tag synonyms

Tags: discussion

May I ask to check the [tags synonyms page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) once in a while, and vote on the (currently 13) pending synonym proposals. The oldest one is 3 weeks old, and until now none of them have votes. Thanks.

Comment: This is one of the "out of the way" pages that is difficult to remember going to unless you are specifically thinking "I want to see if there are tags to merge". There are a few Meta.SO posts on improving the visibility of pending synonyms, but none really have gotten a lot of votes (So go bump them / upvote them!).

Comment: Until something is implemented, making a meta post (or bumping this one) will alert everyone to check the synonyms page.

Comment: @W5VO - Yes, the "out of the way" is the reason I posted this. To be honest I hadn't looked at it much in the past either, but currently I'm trying to clean up tags a bit. I'll bump this one if there are again many pending synonym proposals.